# SSLHandshake is very slow with HttpUrlConnectiom

Tags: java, http, ssl, https

I send HTTP request by using HttpUrlConnection.
I send request and take response code. And after that I get the response's inputstream and use it.

My code is something like that:

```
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection(proxy);
con.setConnectTimeout(10000);
con.setReadTimeout(15000);

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();

InputStream is =    con.getInputStream();

...
```

The code works excellent.But I have a problem. Sometimes it waits 3-4 minutes before sending HTTP request and after a long time wait it continue working succesfully. So the only problem is why it sometimes waits 3 or 4 minutes before sending http reqeust succesfully.

I debug my code and I guess I found where it waits. Here is the SSL debug results.

**DEBUG RESULT:**

trigger seeding of SecureRandom

done seeding SecureRandom

::::::IT WAITS HERE 3 OR 4 MINUTES.AND THEN CONTINUE:::::

Allow unsafe renegotiation: false

Allow legacy hello messages: true

Is initial handshake: true

Is secure renegotiation: false

%% No cached client session

*** ClientHello, TLSv1

......(and continue)
.......

Note that it only happens sometimes,not always. I'm very confused about it.Any idea ?

Comment: We can only guess but my guess is this little note in the documentation of `SecureRandom`: `Depending on the implementation, the generateSeed and nextBytes methods may block as entropy is being gathered, for example, if they need to read from /dev/random on various Unix-like operating systems.` This cause would be consistent with it only happening occasionally.

Comment: Can you tell more details about it.What can I do for the solution.And yes it only happen sometimes.

Comment: There were already hints like possible garbage collection when you asked the questions earlier. It does not make much sense to ask exactly the question multiple times and remove the earlier questions if you don't like the comments or answers. It might just be that the problem is your question.

Comment: No one can solve the problem until now.Here is stackoverflow and I hope somebody can help me in here.That's because I've asked the same  questions.